# Cosa sono i "baffi a coda di topo"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Stranita, passava in rassegna i volti degli sconosciuti che sventolando il passi venivano a ritirare i parenti. Ceffi duri sormontati da coppole, musi tagliati nella pietra, **baffi** a manubrio e **a coda di topo**, nasi a uncino, occhi di pece e acquamarina, pelli di cuoio e di alabastro, brufoli ed efelidi, mariti, nonni, suoceri, madri addolorate, trentenni in cerca della sposa vista solo in fotografia, un vecchio triste che ululava il nome del figlio.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa sono i "baffi a coda di topo"? Ho trovato la locuzione ["coda di topo" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/coda-di-topo/), ma la definizione non sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Una ricerca su Google, però,  mi ha fatto vedere che "baffi a coda di topo" è un'espressione usata in altri testi. Per esempio, si può leggere nei [*Nuovi racconti romani*](https://books.google.es/books?id=l5qgDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT187&lpg=PT187&dq=%22baffi+a+coda+di+topo%22&source=bl&ots=jyTTC8r5uH&sig=n4eUErY0u3eUGTP_m1SX1hxAdHQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJqNnhvNvfAhWQZ1AKHV74BNUQ6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22baffi%20a%20coda%20di%20topo%22&f=false) di Moravia.

Comment: “A coda di topo” mi fa pensare a qualcosa che si assottiglia progressivamente, come la lenza nella definizione del Treccani, ma non solo. Avrei pensato che fosse più diffuso, ma non lo trovo definito esplicitamente così.

Comment: [segue] C'è però qualche sporadico esempio, come [qui](https://books.google.it/books?id=zhxOAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA57&lpg=RA1-PA57&dq=%22a+coda+di+topo%22&source=bl&ots=GFh7tgJz7s&sig=TQPRhrTpJ6EJJoSpnYFxDr1XA_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCnvne0dvfAhVFNOwKHZF2C384KBDoATAIegQIAhAB#v=onepage&q=%22a%20coda%20di%20topo%22&f=false), dove si parla di una “Lima che ha la forma di un cono allungatissimo, dette a coda di topo”.

Comment: Come [questi](http://1.citynews-today.stgy.ovh/~media/horizontal-mid/34125392955197/baffi-famosi-2.jpg)?

Comment: Non sempre gli scrittori adoperano modi di dire che “già esistono”; anzi, spesso sono gli scrittori a introdurre nuovi modi di dire. Può benissimo essere accaduto che Mazzucco ha visto un paio di baffi come quelli di Dalí paragonandoli a code di topo; poi li ha considerati adatti ai personaggi che descrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non sempre gli scrittori adoperano modi di dire che “già esistono”; anzi, spesso sono gli scrittori a introdurre nuovi modi di dire. Può benissimo essere accaduto che Mazzucco abbia visto un paio di baffi come quelli di Salvador Dalí paragonandoli a code di topo; poi li abbia considerati adatti ai personaggi che descrive. Oppure che abbia sentito da qualcuno il modo di dire.

[image: Dali]

Una conferma ce l'ho da un volume dei [quaderni ibero-americani](https://books.google.it/books?id=K_ziAAAAMAAJ&q=%22baffi%20a%20coda%20di%20topo%22&dq=%22baffi%20a%20coda%20di%20topo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip9sn8z-rfAhXMPOwKHYp_B3kQ6AEIPjAD) in cui trovo

> Dai baffi a coda di topo di Dalì a Picasso che si fa fotografare con un piccione sulla testa non c'è gran divario dì stile.